# Typescript interface set default value for specific property

Tags: typescript

The given property could be boolean or undefined.How can I make the field "**option**" be false in case we don't specify it explicitly?

```
interface ITest {
    option?: boolean;
}
    
class Test implements ITest {
   readonly option?: boolean;

   constructor() {
     this.option = false;
   }
}

const tests: Test[] = [{
  //  option: false
}]
```

Comment: Use a class instead.

Comment: Thanks! Post updated.

Comment: Yeah I was about to say, need a constructor for default initialization. For booleans in JS though I'd be curious of the use-case, it's still falsey even undefined so why check for explicit false value?

Comment: Nothing specific, I'm just currently studying TS and exploring its depths.I followed the advice above and I think it worked.

Comment: Nice, just should write `new Test()` when initializing in your array